# Looking for some one who has implemented Moneris recurring payments for a website subcription

Tags: payment, gateway

My client is using moneris as our payment gateway for a new subscription based website that I am working on.

I will be using the language PHP

I've looked through their documentation for PHP api and am comfortable with how it works, it seems very straight forward.

One thing was missing in the documentation for me though. There is mention of how to start a recurring payment, how to update a recurring payment, but no mention of how to query a recurring payment?

Some payment gateways allow you to have a POST back URL of sorts that get updates on recurring billing status. This does not seem to be possible with moneris.

How do I go about automatting the process of tracking recurring payments with Moneris? I'd like for my customers to log in and be able to view their transaction history on my site.

This information will also make it easier for me to know when to close accounts. Ie. when a payment fails to go through, or a credit card expires? I don't want for my cleint(owner of website) to have to keep track of the recurring payments and cancel accounts manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got an answer from Moneris:

> Hi David,   We currently do not have a reporting API or any way of
>   posting the information from our recurring payments back to your
>   server.  It is something that has been mentioned previously and is
>   being looked into.  We do not have a current ETA on such a solution.

Comment: To follow up, I've combatted this problem by writing my own cron job on the web server that does the recurring payments. Moneris has a feature called the vault that you can use to save credit card numbers (since it can be dangerous legally to store them yourself in your own database) I used the vault to store credit cards after someone signs up, and then look up the valid credit card when it is time to charge the subscription. This gives me the ability to track the records of the payments in my own database.