# Recurring billing in activemerchant using Moneris Canada

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, payment-gateway, activemerchant

I am working on an e-commerce site which allows user to purchase a product in 3 monthly instalments. Previously I was using Stripe payment gateway for instalments. I was using Stripe webhooks to update my system after instalments gets paid.

Now I have to achieve the same thing using Moneris(Canada) payment gateway. There are official libraries for Java, PHP & .NET but I am using Ruby. I looked into ActiveMerchant. It allows single charge but I couldn't find anything about recurring payment support.

As far as I know there is no any webhook support but I am looking for API's which I can schedule to run to fetch data from Moneris & update my system accordingly.

I would prefer using ActiveMerchant & a bit of custom code to update my system. I am looking for a good starting point which can lead to a better solution given this scenario.

Comment: ActiveMerchant dropped the support for recurring payments. Plus the Moneris documentation sucks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK Moneris at this time doesn't support access to reporting via API so there's no programmatic way of checking that a recurring payment was successful or not, neither through webooks or through reportings.

This answer suggests another solution...

[Looking for some one who has implemented Moneris recurring payments for a website subcription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7883535/looking-for-some-one-who-has-implemented-moneris-recurring-payments-for-a-websit)

...which is basically just storing the credit cards on Moneris in exchange for a token, presumably, (what the poster refers to as "the vault") and then setting up your own scheduler to request payments as needed and getting real-time feedback on success or failure of payments.